# Action not working on active and hold on the div

Tags: javascript, html, css, action

I have a `<div>` with an action. It is working fine on press,
But, if I press and hold then, drag to out side of the `<div>` and release
then not triggering the action.

How do I solve this?
Please see the below code .

```js
function my_btnpressed(){
    console.log("Button pressed.!")
}
```

```css
#my_btn{
  width:300px;
  height:120px;
  background-color:cyan;
  
}
#my_btn:active{
  background-color:green;
}

.btn{
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="my_btn" class="btn" onclick="my_btnpressed()"> Click Me! </div>
```

[JS Fiddle Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/4whdet82/31/)

Comment: I'd assume that *click* is both buttondown AND buttonup

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? I don't understand the issue

Comment: Both your SO snippet and your js fiddle work when I hold my mousebutton down for +- 10 seconds the only time it doesn't work is when I exit the div while holding down the mousebutton but this is expected.

Comment: The click () works if you click and release with the mouse still on top of the div, if you are clicking on it, holding it down, dragging it out of the div and releasing it, it doesn't work.

I don't know and that's your question

Comment: I have edited the question